# Rails 4: Why does this code not save Contact and Company to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently stuck with probably an easy question that somehow though keeps me a bit confused.

Why is Contact and Company not saved to my database in this controller method? I am calling this very same method in another Rails 5 project and 
@company = Company.new(company_params) seems to work just fine.

```
def create
   @company = Company.new(company_params)
   @contact = Contact.new(contact_params) 

 respond_to do |format|
  if @company.valid? && @contact.valid?

    # SuggestionMailer.newcompany_email(@company, @contact.email, @contact.name).deliver_now

    format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully submitted.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

These are the referenced methods:

```
def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:name, :location, :founded_date,  :category, :sub_category,
                                  :business_model, :target_client, :description, :main_url, 
                                  :twitter_url, :angellist_url, :crunchbase_url, :employee_count, 
                                  :all_tags, :category_id, :sub_category_id, :target_client_id, 
                                  :business_model_id)
end

def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

I would very much appreciate a short feedback here. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you forgot to save you `@contact` and `@compnay` Object.

```
def create
   @company = Company.new(company_params)
   @contact = Contact.new(contact_params) 

 respond_to do |format|
  if @company.valid? && @contact.valid?
    # Save your Object here like
    @company = @company.save 
    @contact = @contact.save

    # SuggestionMailer.newcompany_email(@company, @contact.email, @contact.name).deliver_now

    format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully submitted.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```